# MATLAB Installation in Ubuntu 12.04 via terminal

Tags: command-line, matlab

Whenever I try to install MATLAB R2014a in my ubuntu 12.04 via terminal then it shows the following error:

```
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x2c4000 0 0x23fce0 4
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationA (hwnd=0x47810, filter=0x5de278,flags=0x00000001) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationA (hwnd=0x47810, filter=0x5de278,flags=0x00000001) returns a fake device notification handle!
err:service:service_send_start_message service L"Mobile Partner. RunOuc" failed to start
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"Mobile Partner. RunOuc" failed to start: 1053
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
vivekruhela@ubuntu:~$ fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x2c4000 0 0x23fcc0 4
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x3d4000 0 0x23fce0 4
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x309000 0 0x23fcb0 4
Visual C++ 2005 Run Time Libraries are installed correctly.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x309000 0 0x23fcb0 4
Visual C++ 2005 Run Time Libraries are installed correctly.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x240000 0 0x7ffd9d2a3430 4
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x360000 0 0x23fce0 4
Visual C++ 2008 Run Time Libraries are installed correctly.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x240000 0 0x7ffc54f245f0 4
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x360000 0 0x23fce0 4
Visual C++ 2008 Run Time Libraries are installed correctly.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x761000 0 0x22e640 4
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x9a0170 1 9a0000: stub
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 2
java.io.IOException: Invalid parameter
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler$MeteredStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.publish(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.instutil.logging.AppLoggerImpl.logLevel(AppLoggerImpl.java:170)
    at com.mathworks.instutil.logging.AppLoggerImpl.logMsg(AppLoggerImpl.java:151)
    at com.mathworks.instutil.logging.AppLoggerImpl.dumpStoredMessages(AppLoggerImpl.java:122)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.printPreviouslyLoggedMessages(WizardLauncher.java:239)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.initLogger(WizardLauncher.java:222)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.startWizard(WizardLauncher.java:140)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.start(WizardLauncher.java:77)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.AbstractLauncher.launch(AbstractLauncher.java:27)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.AbstractLauncher.launchStandalone(AbstractLauncher.java:18)
    at com.mathworks.professionalinstaller.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:20)
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl discovery via DHCP not supported
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006efe2e32, pid=51, tid=52
#
# JRE version: 7.0_11-b21
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x2a2e32]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# Z:\home\vivekruhela\hs_err_pid51.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Can anybody help me? I need it for my project and I am new to Ubuntu. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you are sure, that this is Ubuntu?

Comment: Why use wine when Matlab is available for linux?

Comment: I m trying to install matlab using wine because ./install is not working. Can you suggest me how to install matlab via terminal in Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks

Comment: I have two versions of matlab(2009a and 2014a) in which I am using 2014a in windows operating system. So I want to install any of them in ubuntu. but how....?

Comment: Can any body tell me from where to download the linux version of matlab. Last time I was doing the silly mistake to install the window version of matlab in linux. I got one installation file for linux but there is a licence error. So from where should I download the linux version of matlab.. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: From the Mathworks' website you can download any version of Matlab for Linux. However, you need to create an account for that.